# Iterate over pointer to an array of char pointers

Tags: c, arrays, loops, pointers

Lets say I have the following code:

```
char *array[] = {"one", "two", "three"};
char *(*arrayPtr)[] = &array;
```

How do I iterate over array? I've tried doing this but doesn't work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); i++) {
    printf("%s\n", (*arrayPtr + i));
}
```

Comment: Any reason a plain `array[i]` can't be used by you?

Comment: @StoryTeller I have to pass the variable array as to pointer to a struct

Comment: First things first, if you think you need to take an array address as in `&array`, you are probably wrong.

Comment: @n.m. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Pointers to arrays are rarely needed, mainly when they are elements of larger arrays (e.g with 2d arrays). In most cases a pointer to the first element of an array is more convenient and less confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheme you have is missing a derference. `*arrayPtr + i` is the address of the i-th element of the array. Meaning it's a `char**`. You need to at least dereference that:

```
printf("%s\n", *(*arrayPtr + i));
```

However, that isn't valid C you have there, since you omitted the array size when defining the pointer. I hope it's not the actual code you wrote.

Also, note that you can use the subscript operator as [**Blagovest Buyukliev**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265804/blagovest-buyukliev) pointed out, but be weary of operator precedence. It's `(*arrayPtr)[i]` and not `*arrayPtr[i]`.

Comment: Alternatively, `(*arrayPtr)[i]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: Do you mean the array size when defining 'array' or 'arrayPtr'?

Comment: @SanketDeshpande - `arrayPtr`. It's a must have there. The size for `array` is deduced from the initializer, so no problem there.

Comment: @StoryTeller So I need to have `char *(*arrayPtr)[sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])] = &array;`, right?

Comment: @SanketDeshpande - That's a possibility yes. But personally, a plain `char**` that's passed with a size parameter seems less verbose.